# Meaning: channel vs river

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between a channel and a river?

**UPDATE**

I understand the difference between *canal* and river, but why there is also channel? Is that the same as canal?

Comment: It is the exact same difference as in your mother tongue, канал vs. река. Please consult a dictionary, or Wikipedia, or common sense, or any of the other commonly-available references linked below. Thank you.

Comment: no, it is not. Канал tends to be аn artificial waterway and река is a natural waterway. So, канал is canal, not channel.

Comment: Ah. I suspect you mean to ask about _canal_, rather than _channel_. Though ultimately from the same source, these are very different words in English: See Bradd Szonye's answer.

Comment: no again, I understand the difference between canal and river. The embarrassing thing was why there are two words that seem to have close meaning and how exactly channel differ from river (as I know how canal does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as the relationship between *cup* and *coffee*:

- Literally, the channel is the course in the ground that the river water flows through.
- Figuratively, we often use *channel* to refer to the body of water as a whole, as in the *English Channel.*

Comment: Oxford appears to disagree.  [Channel](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/channel) - a length of water wider than a strait, joining two larger areas of water, especially two seas **or** the navigable part of a waterway.  "Channel" can infact be literally the body of water, but your definition is listed as well: a hollow bed for a natural or artificial waterway.

Comment: Ah, I guess it has two meanings then. Looks like _channel_ is a little different from _river channel._ I may update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I like your answer anyway :) Thanks Lumberjack, though.